# introducing delay within async.forEachSeries

Tags: node.js, node-async

```
async.forEachSeries(jList, function(json, cb) {
                setTimeout(foo,600000);
                function1(j,function(){}
};
```

I want to introduce a delay before each entry of the iterator is picked up for execution. I tried a setTimeOut but it is not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

in your code the setTimeout sets a timer and a code to run later once the timer is triggered. but your code continues to run and will not stop the thread and wait for the timeout to finish. 
so you can go about it 2 ways ...to run some kind of endless loop that waits for the time you want to pass and then continue ***or*** set timers to trigger in the interval you want times the index. 
then your thread is free to run and its not stuck waiting.

```
var forEach = require('async-foreach').forEach;
var timeoutLength = 3000;

forEach(["a", "b", "c"], function (item, index) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("each", item, index);
    }, timeoutLength * index);
});
```

Comment: Please edit your answer, and explain why this is a good solution.